# table==1 was unexpected at this time batch file

Tags: sql, database, batch-file

I am trying to apply multiple SQL scripts to an Ingres database (using a vnode setup). The testing phase will require it done to four databases. Trying to nip this annoyance in the bud I've started a batch file but receive the error above.
Many of the solutions found suggest that the batch file will evaluate everything within a block when it starts but I cannot see the forest for the trees. I have a suspicion that the parts in :1ST and :2ND are causing the problems but they need to be done.
SQL, Batch and command window output are below

---

```
UPDATE core SET sysflag='O'
```

---

```
@ECHO off
SET VN1=dave
SET DB1=dbtest1
SET DB2=dbtest2
SET SQL1=open.sql
SET SQL2=open.sql

:MENU
CLS
ECHO 1 - Leave
ECHO 2 - Database1
ECHO 3 - Database2

SET /P M=Choose then press ENTER:
IF "%M%"=="1" GOTO EOF
IF "%M%"=="2" GOTO 1ST
IF "%M%"=="3" GOTO 2ND
GOTO MENU

:1ST
SET DATABASE=%VN1%::%DB1%
GOTO RUNSQL
:2ND
SET DATABASE=%VN1%::%DB2%
GOTO RUNSQL

:RUNSQL
ECHO Applying SQLs to %DATABASE%
SQL %DATABASE% < %SQL1% > log_%SQL1%.txt
PAUSE
SQL %DATABASE% < %SQL2% > log_%SQL2%.txt
PAUSE
GOTO MENU

:EOF
```

---

```
C:\Users\me\BUILD>IF UPDATE core SET sysflag='O'==1 GOTO EOF
```

Comment: if you get put REM in fromt off the @ECHO OFF you could easily spot where it goes wrong. I don't see anything suspicous here...

Comment: That's more or less how it outputs IF errors in batch files "IF %M%==1 GOTO EOF", you should check there first.  @rene makes perfect sense as without echo off each line prints and the error would display immediately after.  Basically your %M% is equal to "table" instead of 1 which is the result of your input.  What's the input?

Comment: User input was 2. The sql is being used as the standard input for the menu section somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting the value of `%M%` to have 1, 2, or 3. But somehow the value is `UPDATE core`. The IF statement fails because there is a space in the middle of the left value. Token delimiters like space must be escaped, or the entire string on each side should be quoted. You could change your statement to `IF "%M%"=="1" GOTO EOF` to eliminate the error, but it still will not give the results you want.

The SET /P statement reads the value from stdin. I assume you have not typed the value `UPDATE core`, but instead your input was either redirected or piped. You are feeding your script the wrong value.

You should add error handling so that the code does not fall through to :1ST if the input is not 1, 2, or 3.

---

You can explicitly redirect input to the console for your SET /P statement. That way it will ignore the redirected input or piped input that was provided for the batch script.

```
<con: SET /P "M=Choose then press ENTER: "
```

But something seems wrong with your whole design. If you are piping or redirecting input for the script, then it doesn't make sense to present an interactive menu of choices in a loop. What happens if the user never presses 1 to quit? Eventually the piped or redirected input will be exhausted, and then you have problems.

Comment: UPDATE core is the first line of the SQL file. I changed this to be the whole statement of UPDATE core SET sysflag='O' and the error becomes C:\Users\me\BUILD>IF UPDATE core SET sysflag='O'==1 GOTO EOF. The SQL is being read as the standard input and overwriting the menu choice. With the quotes described above the whole thing just hangs at the first SQL

Comment: @Ritchie - You understand your problem. Now you need to either change your script, change your input, or both.

Comment: Thats the problem, I am unaware of a fix to stop the standard input overwriting the menu choice. I input is 2. It thinks the input is the SQL. I have used the quotes and stopped it falling through but these changes make the batch file loop endlessly showing %M% as "/p/g" (the last line of the sql file). Is there anyway to create a preprocessed variable for input? This way it would be set, used, discarded then the standard input would be used for the SQL.

Comment: Using the <con: with the menu options stops it scrolling through (even though I've used a "GOTO" that should stop that if it only read the input not input and sql). I'm almost at the point of just doing it properly with a real program instead as this simply doesn't distinguish read in data from input data. Can I create a localised variable for the menu option system? Is there another to do this?